# best way to index array with a float between 0 and 1

Tags: arrays, indexing, floating-point

So say you have an array n long and you want to access it using a random float f between 0 and 1, what would most people suggest as the most efficient approach.

At first I considered  `array[ (int)f*n ]` but then if the float is precisely 1.0 this will crash.

`array[ (int)f*(n-1) ]` doesn't work as there is such a small chance of any random float being exactly 1.0 that the last element almost never comes up.

This kinda logically leads to something like `array[ (int) ( (f == 1.0)? f*(n-1) : f*n) ]` but that's suddenly very complicated and seems like it has the chance to potentially be quite slow, i was just wondering if there was a more simple or elegant solution

Comment: What solutions are meaningful or better than others depends on the purposes for which this is being done. So you should explain the context. If the goal is merely to select a random element in the array, it is generally better to start with an integer random number rather than a floating-point number. If you must use a floating-point number, then `int x = f*n; if (n <= x) x = 0;` may serve to select an array index. Instead of clamping the index to the last element, it wraps it, which may give a better balance to the first and last intervals. But it depends on circumstances.

Comment: I mean it's more of a general problem that I have encountered a few times, say for example if I have some perlin noise and I want to visualise it in layers. I was thinking maybe either array[ f*( n - MIN_FLOAT_VALUE ) ] could work or maybe simply reading the float as an int and % with n

Comment: I'd suggest not doing either of those: you'd want to use `FLT_EPSILON` but then you have to worry about what happens if `f=0`.  using a modulus (`%`) is likely slower as it's an expensive operation for the CPU to execute, and I'd still worry about it introducing bias

Comment: @EricPostpischil isn't it just `(int)(f*n) % n`

Comment: @aka.nice: Division is often more expensive than compare-and-branch, especially when the branch is correctly predicted.

Answer (score 1):

The performance impact of either your or Eric's suggestion is going to be negligible.

The `f=1.` branch will be taken so rarely that your CPU's branch predictor will basically always do the correct thing.  If `f` is a 64bit float generated uniformly at random then you're essentially never going to see a value 1 anyway.

I'd be tempted to remove the redundant computation from your code and use an unsigned type for clarity:

```c
array[(size_t)(f == 1.0 ? n-1 : f*n)]
```

but I suggest you just use Eric's version (for reason's pointed out by @chux in the comments).  Note that there's essentially no difference once an optimiser gets to work its magic: https://godbolt.org/z/ovjG7KK11

I tested these with a fast RNG (an inlined [xoshiro256plus](https://prng.di.unimi.it/)) and the difference was less than 1% of total runtime (2**28 iterations taking ~650ms on my laptop, repeated 10 times to get an idea of variance).  I presume a Perlin generator is going to be significantly more expensive, hence this already tiny difference will be diluted even further.

Note, to see double's getting rounded the "wrong way", try compiling/running the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fenv.h>

int
main()
{
    const double val = nextafter(1, 0);
    const int n = 7;

    {
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON

        fesetround(FE_UPWARD);

        printf("%.20f %.20f\n", val, val * n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this prints out:

```
0.99999999999999988898 7.00000000000000000000
```

on my Intel laptop.

Comment: Hmmm, `f*n` with `f` values very near 1.0 and/or uncertain rounding mode may risk a product of `n`.  Might be better to multiply first and then compare to avoid an out -of-range access.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica is that possible?  if `f=1-epsilon`, then the result moves away from `n` at a rate of `n*epsilon` so I'm not sure how rounding modes would affect things.  any suggestions of modes/values?

Comment: " I'm not sure how rounding modes would affect things." is the point.  `f == 1.0 ? n-1 : f*n` relies on `f*n` never converting to `n` for all `0 <= f<1`, all `n` and various rounding modes including round toward infinity (and various [`FLT_EVAL_METHOD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#IEEE_754_floating-point_support)).  Perhaps one could as you have it with much analysis, yet I see no benefit over `int index = f*n; if (index >= n) index = n-1;` with the later being much index safer.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica just tested this and whenever the FPU is set to round up you get back `n`.  guess my intuitions about FP behavior were wrong again!

Comment: Note: on my machine, `n==7` returned 6.999..., but `n == 9` returned 9.0.  [YMMV](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ymmv)

Answer (score 1):

> `array[ (int) ( (f == 1.0)? f*(n-1) : f*n) ]` but that's suddenly very complicated and seems like it has the chance to potentially be quite slow, i was just wondering if there was a more simple or elegant solution

**Code for defined behavior first**

Form the index through multiplication and cast.  Then compare.

```
unsigned index = (unsigned) (f * n);
if (index >= n) index = n - 1;
```

An integer compare is certainly not complicated.

The index (given OP's conditions) is unquestionable in the `[0....n)` range - no UB.

As to efficiency, profile it.  Be wary of perceived [micro-optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99445/is-micro-optimisation-important-when-coding#comment180450_99445) gains.

Also be wary of assuming that if `f < 1.0`, `(int)(f * n) < n` is *always* true.

---

Notes: Code assumes `int n` in `[1...INT_MAX]` range, `some_FP_type f` in the `[0.0... 1.0]` range, and `FP_EVAL_METHOD` and rounding mode not specified.  Code uses `unsigned` to cope with `n == INT_MAX` initially forming an `index` of `INT_MAX + 1u`.

---

**Deeper**

> best way to index array with a float between 0 and 1

Sometimes best to step back and consider the larger picture.  Given `f` in the inclusive [0.0 ... 1.0] range, the *best* may involve the end array elements getting 1/2 the chance as the other elements.

For a `n == 5`, then

```
0.0   ... 0.125 maps to 0
0.125 ... 0.375 maps to 1
0.375 ... 0.625 maps to 2
0.625 ... 0.375 maps to 3
0.875 ... 1.0   maps to 4
```

In other words, what is really *best* to handle mapping and concerns of `f` at/near 1.0 is often best addressed knowing the larger problem.  That was not posted by OP.

Other times I see the floating point `f` as [0.0 ... 1.0] scaling is an artifact of what should have been an integer only problem where edge cases are clearly handled.